# Anbox-Modules-dkms Won't Install

Tags: modprobe, anbox

I'm having trouble installing the modules sudo modprobe ashmem_linux and sudo modprobe binder_linux. Every time I try the code I get this message in my Terminal

modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'ashmem_linux': Required key not available

How can I fix this.

Comment: actually I get this error on `binder_linux`, `modprobe ashmem_linux` (Ubuntu 19.04, Kernel 5.0.7) seems to have worked.  Not sure how I can confirm that with the task incomplete like this.

Comment: There are some notes here about signing your module before loading.  Personally, I'm not a fan because it more or less implies stuff around secure boot, and I can't know the implications or impact of just doing that blindly.  `Anbox` install documentation isn't telling me there's a minimal kernel I need to have. Or is that located somewhere else?